# Copy worksheets from multiple workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I need to write a macro that can either pull a specific worksheet from every workbook in a folder without opening them (preferable if possible due to the size of these workbooks) or open each workbook one at a time and copy the worksheet.

Every post on this topic I have been able to find, the path has been static and is specified in the macro, but for the purposes of this macro there will be two different paths that this will need to work for, and those will change every week.

Can someone show me how to code the macro so that it asks for the path?

Is it possible to pull a worksheet from a workbook without opening the workbook?

Thanks,

Aaron

Comment: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/112499-extract-data-without-opening-files.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) to prompt for the path.

Comment: Thanks. This did the trick. I also discovered that since I need to copy the whole worksheet and not just the data on the worksheet I have to open each file.